# Is there a maven archtype for creating a console app?

Tags: maven-2, maven-shade-plugin

Is it possible to generate a maven stub project via `mvn archetype:generate` that has a main function, and part of the build process includes making a App.cmd/App.sh to run the app from a shell?

It seems that I need the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to create a console app jar with wrapper scripts for command line startup. However, I don't know if their is an archtype to configure a maven project to use it and create an empty console app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "Simple" archetype creates a maven project with a class that has a "main" method.  Use that with your maven-shade-plugin to create an executable jar and you are good to go!

Answer (score 9):

"**org.apache.maven.archetypes**" "**maven-archetype-quickstart**" (version 1.1) worked for me.

```java
/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```